# Scala: Is there a default class if no class is defined?

Tags: scala

According to [this](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html), Scala methods belong to a class. However, if I define a method in REPL or in a script that I then execute using scala, what class does the method belong to ?

```
scala> def hoho(str:String) = {println("hoho " + str)}
hoho: (str: String)Unit

scala> hoho("rahul")
hoho rahul
```

In this example, what class does the method belong to ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The REPL wraps all your statements (actually rewrites your statements) in objects automagically. You can see it in action if you print the intermediate code by using the `-Xprint:typer` option:

```
scala> def hoho(str:String) = {println("hoho " + str)}
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line1 {
  final object $read extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line1.$read = {
      $read.super.this();
      ()
    };
    final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
      def this(): object $line1.$read.$iw = {
        $iw.super.this();
        ()
      };
      final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
        def this(): object $line1.$read.$iw.$iw = {
          $iw.super.this();
          ()
        };
        def hoho(str: String): Unit = scala.this.Predef.println("hoho ".+(str))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So your method `hoho` is really `$line1.$read.$iw.$iw.hoho`. Then when you use `hoho("foo")` later on, it'll rewrite to add the package and outer objects.

Additional notes: for scripts, `-Xprint:typer` (`-Xprint:parser`) reveals that the code is wrapped inside a code block in the `main(args:Array[String])` of an object `Main`. You have access to the arguments as `args` or `argv`.

Comment: Thanks. Does the same happen if I were to save the method definition in a .scala script and execute it using scala <myscript> ?

Comment: @Rahul, I've added the info for script, the mechanism is different.