# What really happens behind the Scala runtime/REPL when running a '.scala' program?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I run something like the following from the command line, what really happens?

```
> scala hello.scala
```

Is there a hello.class generated, executed, and then discarded? Or does Scala behave somehow like an interpreter in this case? I am just thinking that, of course, I cannot do the same for Java:

```
> java hello.java
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there is a hello.class generated. The compiler will wrap your code inside a `Main` object, compile it then execute `Main.main`, given hello.scala of

```
println(args.mkString)
println(argv.mkString)
```

If you run with the `-Xprint:parser` option: `scala -Xprint:parser hello.scala foo bar` you'll see how the code gets rewritten:

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(argv: Array[String]): scala.Unit = {
      val args = argv;
      {
        final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
          def <init>() = {
            super.<init>();
            ()
          };
          println(args.mkString);
          println(argv.mkString)
        };
        new $anon()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code is then compiled (I believe to a memory filesystem - but I'm not sure) and executed. Looking at [`ScriptRunner`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ScriptRunner.scala), I see that a temporary directory is created under the default temp folder. For instance looking at my system, I see a bunch of `%TEMP%/scalascript*` folders.

Note that even in the interpreter, the code is not interpreted. See [Scala: Is there a default class if no class is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279796/scala-is-there-a-default-class-if-no-class-is-defined/7280136#7280136) for more info (it's really being rewritten, compiled and evaluated).

Comment: How does the compiler make `val args = argv`? What if one types `println(arguments.mkString)`? Will there be a `val arguments = argv`?

Comment: @PeterSchmitz, `args` and `argv` are hard-coded, see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Parsers.scala#L358 and around line 388. Those names are simply conventions from C (`argv`) and Java programming (`args`). If you type `println(arguments.mkString)` you'll get a compiler error because `arguments` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, didn´t know that. Though I´m a bit surprised! As far as I learned "hard-coded" isn´t good in general...

Comment: @Peter it's just an identifier, like the entry method is called `main`, and the method for printing something is called `println`. I don't see the problem or why you would want it any other way... after all it's got to be called something

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Acknowledged, `println` and especially `main` are also "hard-coded", but I was confused that a method argument name like `args` was "hard-coded" then (but I´m fine with that, there has to be a name for `args`, because not explicitly statable), which I can choose when having the main method in class filled by myself instead of been constructed by the REPL(or perhaps extending `App`). Everything´s fine :D

Comment: How can there be a hello.class with a class called Main?

Comment: @nafg, yeah technically the class is not called `hello.class`. As you see from `-Xprint:parser`, the class may be called `Main$`. I took the question to be, is there a class that is compiled, run and discarded? Not specifically is it called `hello.class`...

Comment: So if it really creates those files won't two scala scripts overwrite each other?

Comment: @nafg, the class files are created into a temporary directory under `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`. See https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.1/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ScriptRunner.scala#L105. The directory is cleaned up on the script exit.

Comment: @huynhjl So you can't run two scripts at the same time?

Comment: I think you can. It will just create the class files into different directories (the directories are suffixed with some random/unique digits specific to that run)...