# Trying to understand how classes declared on the REPL are treated internally

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to understand how scoping works in the REPL. I tried following Section 5.1.1 of Joshua Suereth's book Scala in depth.This is on Windows XP, Java 7 and Scala 2.9.1. I declare a class `Dinner` in the REPL. The binding `Dinner` exists in the local scope. Then I instantiate because it is locally bound.

```
scala> class Dinner {
 | val veggie="broccoli"
 | def announceDinner(veggie: String){
 | println("Dinner happens to be tasteless " + veggie + " soup")
 | }
 | }
defined class Dinner

scala> new Dinner
res1: Dinner = Dinner@27fb77
```

So far so good. The name `Dinner` was bound locally and we could also construct a  `val x` that could hold a reference to `new Dinner`.

From what I know so far, The REPL will wrap the above code in objects internally. Okay, my knowledge of Scala is not quite as deep yet and I am trying to understand how Class might be internally wrapped by the REPL.

Is there an REPL command that can help me evaluate these objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What really happens behind the scala runtime/repl when running a .scala program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655165/what-really-happens-behind-the-scala-runtime-repl-when-running-a-scala-program)

Comment: I will add more clarity to what I was really looking to understand. I was trying to find out if the class definition is preserved when it was wrapped into an 'object' internally. Maybe it does not matter because I can operate on the class and invoke its method? I did look at that post before but did not think it was the exact answer to my question and I ended up posting my question.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a small example what you want for an output? I don't understand what you want to see.

Comment: It's really unclear what the you want, much less what problem you are trying to solve. I suggest that you just get on with it, and, when you actually have a problem you need solving, you come back with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes a very quick and dirty way to what is going on in the REPL.

Invoke the REPL with scala -Xprint:typer

```
scala> class Dinner {
     |   val veggie="broccoli"
     |   def announceDinner(veggie: String){
     |   println("Dinner happens to be tasteless " + veggie + " soup")
     |   }
     |  }
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line1 {
  final object $read extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line1.$read = {
      $read.super.this();
      ()
    };
    final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
      def this(): object $line1.$read.$iw = {
        $iw.super.this();
        ()
      };
      final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
        def this(): object $line1.$read.$iw.$iw = {
          $iw.super.this();
          ()
        };
        class Dinner extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
          def this(): $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner = {
            Dinner.super.this();
            ()
          };
          private[this] val veggie: java.lang.String = "broccoli";
          <stable> <accessor> def veggie: java.lang.String = Dinner.this.veggie;
          def announceDinner(veggie: String): Unit = scala.this.Predef.println("Dinner happens to be tasteless ".+(veggie).+(" soup"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line1 {
  final object $eval extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line1.$eval = {
      $eval.super.this();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val $print: String = {
      $read.$iw.$iw;
      "defined class Dinner\012"
    };
    <stable> <accessor> def $print: String = $eval.this.$print
  }
}

defined class Dinner
```

As you can check above `Dinner` ends up wrapped into `$line1.$read.$iw.$iw`. Now let's see what happens next:

```
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line2 {
  final object $read extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line2.$read = {
      $read.super.this();
      ()
    };
    final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
      def this(): object $line2.$read.$iw = {
        $iw.super.this();
        ()
      };
      import $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner;
      final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
        def this(): object $line2.$read.$iw.$iw = {
          $iw.super.this();
          ()
        };
        private[this] val res0: $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner = new $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner();
        <stable> <accessor> def res0: $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner = $iw.this.res0
      }
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line2 {
  final object $eval extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line2.$eval = {
      $eval.super.this();
      ()
    };
    lazy private[this] var $result: $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner = {
      $eval.this.$print;
      $line2.$read.$iw.$iw.res0
    };
    private[this] val $print: String = {
      $read.$iw.$iw;
      "res0: $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner = ".+(scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.replStringOf($line2.$read.$iw.$iw.res0, 1000))
    };
    <stable> <accessor> def $print: String = $eval.this.$print
  }
}
```

Basically the same thing as before but using `$line2` instead of `$line1`. Notice the `import $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Dinner` right before `$line2.$read.$iw.$iw`.

This way we can see why defining companion objects in two different lines doesn't work, they end up wrapped into different objects and companions need to be defined in the same scope/source file.

Comment: That helps a lot. That is the problem I wanted to have a solution to. To see what was going on in the REPL

Comment: You can also try scala -Xprint:parser, it's possible it will give a little more succinct results. BTW, don't forget to mark the question as correct. :)

Comment: Am I allowed to "thank you"? Is that considered bad etiquette on stackoverflow? How do I mark the question as correct? I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I have no idea to both questions. I suppose you find the answer for the 2nd. Anyways, I accept your thank you and give a you are welcome back.