# SCALA: Type of object

Tags: scala

what is the type of this object?

```
class Zad1[A,B](val fst:A, val snd:B) {
  override def toString: String = "(" + fst +","+snd+")"
}

object Zad1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val v = new Zad1[Int, String](1, "2")
    println(v)
  }
}
```

I tried to print the class name with :

```
 println(v.getClass) // would print: class $line8.$read$$iw$$iw$Zad1
```

Comment: println(v.getClass.getName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a singleton `object` is its singleton type, ergo, the type of `Zad1` is `Zad1.type`.

Comment: From the question it appears he wants to know the type of `v`, not `Zad1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to how Scala REPL works.
Though you type just:

```
scala> class Zad1[A,B](val fst:A, val snd:B) {...}
```

REPL wraps it into a series of other objects(`$line8.$read.$iw.$iw`), so `getClass` returns `class $line8.$read$$iw$$iw$Zad1`.

Read about it here:
[Trying to understand how classes declared on the REPL are treated internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549174/trying-to-understand-how-classes-declared-on-the-repl-are-treated-internally)

If you run the same as a Scala program(not from REPL), `getClass` will return something much readable, e.g. `class com.example.Zad1`