# How to get the name of the current script?

Tags: scala, ammonite

How do I get the name of the current script?

For example if I run `myscript.sc`, I'd like to know the value of `myscript`
I need this for killing previous instances of the script, still running.

Comment: Executing `this.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath` command gives a path on `/tmp` folder in a linux system. Maybe that's closest one can get to the actual file name. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655165/what-really-happens-behind-the-scala-runtime-repl-when-running-a-scala-progra#comment22945180_7655610) gave me the idea of changing the tempdir property for the scripts you are running. Any files in that directory would be a potential candidate of a running scala script.

Comment: Another solution that comes to my mind is executing the script with `scala -Xprint:parser filename.sc * 2> tempFile`. The first line of tempFile will always contain a line in the form: `[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // filename.sc: tree ...` which then can be used to extract filename!

Comment: If I write a script with this content: `println(this.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation().getPath)`, then I get `null` as the result.

Comment: I don't know how to pass the `-Xprint:parser` argument to the `amm` binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sourcecode.File()` will return the name of the current script

Comment: Please illustrate with a complete example.

Comment: jwvh: Examples available here: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/sourcecode