# Creating an object dynamically by its name (string)

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a trait and an object inherited from this trait:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def method1(a: Int)
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait {
  def method1(a: Int) = //....
}
```

Assuming I have **only the full name of an object as a string** (namespace + its name) and knowing it's inherited from `MyTrait`, how do I

1. create it at runtime
2. call its method `method1`
3. return it to a calling code so that other clients can use it?

I read about reflection in Scala, but, oddly enough, almost all I found was about creating a **class** at runtime.

**UPDATE:**

I wonder, why doesn't this work:

```
scala>  object MyObject { def method1(a: Int) = 123456 }
defined module MyObject

scala> val cs = Class.forName("MyObject")
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyObject
```

due to the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyObject`

Comment: regarding your edit: code defined in repl session is wrapped and thus [FQCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) is [not simply MyObject, but actually something `$line1.$iw.MyObject` where prefix will be generated by REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279796/scala-is-there-a-default-class-if-no-class-is-defined/7280136#7280136)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get an instance of a singleton scala `object` via reflection, you can try this:

```
package code

object ReflectTest extends App{

  val clazz = Class.forName("code.MyObject$")
  val myObj = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(classOf[MyTrait]).asInstanceOf[MyTrait]
  println(myObj.method1(2))
}

trait MyTrait {
  def method1(a: Int):Int
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait {
  def method1(a: Int) = a + 1
}
```

Now I'm not a big fan of obtaining instances of scala `object`s via reflection (seems kinds silly given that it's a singleton) but maybe you have a valid use case for this.

Comment: what would you use instead of reflection?

Comment: your code is working well. However, what if I need to use the type, not a trait (just in case). If I try to do `get(classOf[MyObject.type])`, it doesn't compile to do the error "class type required but MyObject.type found"

Comment: Objects do not have types, so I think you are out of luck unless you want to refer to it by an implemented trait/class instead (as I did).

Comment: what's `MyObject.type` then?